# Series of Vectors

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ we define sequences of it's elements in a very natural manner, we say that a sequence is a function $x : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and we denote it by $(x_k)$ as in the $n=1$ case. Then defining limit of a sequence and all of that is pretty straightforward and acts like one extension of everything done in $\mathbb{R}$. My doubt is: is there something that stops us from defining the sum of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

All the books I've seem until now define sequences in $\mathbb{R}^n$ but not series. I thought it was possible to define it in an analogous manner: we consider the sequence of partial sums of some sequence $(x_k)$, this will give us another sequence defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we could say that the series converges if the sequence of partial sums converges. Is it possible to do this or there is some inconsistency I'm failing to see?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: I don't see any problem with this, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. The sum of a series of vectors has as its kth component the sum of the series of kth components of vectors in the series, each of which is a series in $\mathbb{R}$, and converges iff all of the component series converge.